# What is "read operations inside transactions can't allow failover"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, transactions

From time to time I got the following exception message on GAE for my
GAE/J app. I searched with Google, no relevant results were found. Does
anyone know about this? Thanks in advance for any response!

The exception message is as below:

> Nested in
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException:
>   Illegal argument; nested exception is
>   **javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   Illegal argument:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   read operations inside transactions
>   can't allow failover**
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:
>   34)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.makeSyncCall(DatastoreApiHelper.java:
>   67)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl
>   $1.run(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:128)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:
>   30)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:
>   111)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:
>   84)
>           at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.get(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:
>   77)
>           at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.RuntimeExceptionWrappingDatastoreService.get(RuntimeExceptionWrappingDatastoreService.java:
>   53)
>           at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.get(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:
>   94)
>           at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.get(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:
>   106)
>           at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.DatastorePersistenceHandler.fetchObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:
>   464)
>           at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadUnloadedFieldsInFetchPlan(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:
>   1627)
>           at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManagerImpl.loadFieldsInFetchPlan(JDOStateManagerImpl.java:
>   1603)
>           at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.performDetachAllOnCommitPreparation(ObjectManagerImpl.java:
>   3192)
>           at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.preCommit(ObjectManagerImpl.java:
>   2931)
>           at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.internalPreCommit(TransactionImpl.java:
>   369)
>           at org.datanucleus.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:256)
>           at org.datanucleus.jpa.EntityTransactionImpl.commit(EntityTransactionImpl.java:
>   104)
>           at org.datanucleus.store.appengine.jpa.DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.commit(DatastoreEntityTransactionImpl.java:
>   55)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.service.Tx.run(Tx.java:39)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.web.controller.TwitterApiController.persistStatus(TwitterApiController.java:
>   309)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.web.controller.TwitterApiController.processStatusesForWebCall(TwitterApiController.java:
>   271)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.web.controller.TwitterApiController.getHomeTimelineUpdates_aroundBody0(TwitterApiController.java:
>   247)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.web.controller.TwitterApiController
>   $AjcClosure1.run(TwitterApiController.java:1)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.web.refine.AuthenticationEnforcement.ajc
>   $around$name_kenyth_playtweets_web_refine_AuthenticationEnforcement
>   $2$439820b7proceed(AuthenticationEnforcement.aj:1)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.web.refine.AuthenticationEnforcement.ajc
>   $around$name_kenyth_playtweets_web_refine_AuthenticationEnforcement
>   $2$439820b7(AuthenticationEnforcement.aj:168)
>           at name.kenyth.playtweets.web.controller.TwitterApiController.getHomeTimelineUpdates(TwitterApiController.java:
>   129)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:43)
>           at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:
>   710)
>           at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:
>   167)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:
>   414)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:
>   402)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:
>   771)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:
>   716)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:
>   647)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:
>   552)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:693)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:
>   511)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:
>   390)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:
>   216)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:
>   182)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:
>   765)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:
>   418)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:
>   195)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:
>   159)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:
>   141)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:
>   90)
>           at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:
>   417)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:
>   71)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:
>   76)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:
>   88)
>           at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:
>   76)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>           at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:
>   97)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:
>   35)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>           at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:
>   43)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler
>   $CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:
>   388)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:
>   216)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:
>   182)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:
>   765)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:
>   418)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:
>   238)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:
>   152)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:
>   542)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection
>   $RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:
>   76)
>           at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:
>   135)
>           at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime.handleRequest(JavaRuntime.java:
>   250)
>           at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime
>   $6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5838)
>           at com.google.apphosting.base.RuntimePb$EvaluationRuntime
>   $6.handleBlockingRequest(RuntimePb.java:5836)
>           at com.google.net.rpc.impl.BlockingApplicationHandler.handleRequest(BlockingApplicationHandler.java:
>   24)
>           at com.google.net.rpc.impl.RpcUtil.runRpcInApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're asking for failover reads, using the new support for this, inside a transaction. As the error message explains, this isn't possible, because in order to be transactional, it has to always read the most recent data. You need to disable failover reads for operations inside transactions.

Comment: But I didn't intentionally enable such feature as failover reads. I just did a normal transaction as described in the GAE/J doc. So of cause I don't know how to disable it and I can't find any documentation about this either. I use JPA with GAE/J. And for this read which generated the exception message I just did a EntityManager.find(class, primaryKey). Could you specify more about this? Thanks!

Comment: Does "<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" />" in the persistence.xml indicate a failover reads in transaction?

Comment: Thanks Nick! With your hints It seems I've solved my problem. I removed that line of configuration above mentioned and deployed to GAE the modified version of my app. At least until now I don't see the exception message.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031214/what-is-read-operations-inside-transactions-cant-allow-failover/3035744#3035744 for a clarification of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First thanks very much for @Nick's answer. Here I clarify the answer in a more direct way specific to my problem in case anyone else encountering the same problem asks for help here.

It seems **with eventual consistency you can't make a query, at least a query by key, within a transaction**, otherwise an exception message described in my question will be thrown. In the [related official documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/overview.html#Datastore_Performance_Features) of Google App Engine, it doesn't point out directly, but with some sentences like this:

> All update operations (create, update,
>   delete) occur in primary storage. A
>   strongly consistent read of an entity
>   may still be one operation or
>   transaction behind, since a
>   transaction is applied after it is
>   committed.

Eventual consistency may need to read from storage location other than the primary one and may conflict with transactional consistency so it is not allowed an eventual-consistency read within a transaction as I see it.

Strong consistency is used by default without any configuration. For my own problem I just deleted the following line in the persistence.xml (JPA):

```
<property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreReadConsistency" value="EVENTUAL" />
```

Thanks again, Nick!

Comment: Please feel free to file a bug: the SDK should really force strong consistency inside a transaction.

Comment: the issue I filed: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3349